# Spring MVC/Thymeleaf - How to insert to two different tables using one input field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have an input field for first name:

```
<input th:field="*{fleet.firstName}" class="signup1" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" autofocus="" required=""/>
```

I have two tables/objects 'fleet' and 'service.' How can I do that if thymeleaf only allows me to use one object per input field?

I tried two input th:field, but it didn't work.
Like:

```
<input th:field="*{fleet.firstName}" th:field="*{service.firstName}" class="signup1" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" autofocus="" required=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible. You could create a DTO object for Thymeleaf with the union of the fields that you are trying to see in the web side. Then, separate this into database tables in you Service tier.

Something like:

**Option 1: WITHOUT th:object**

```
<form th:action="@{/destination}">
      <input type="text" th:value="${service.firstName}" name="service.firstName"/>
      <input type="text" th:value="${fleet.firstName}" name="fleet.firstName"/>
      <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

**Option 2:**

web

```
<form th:action="@{/destination}" th:object="${myThymeleafFormObject}">

public class ThymeleafForm {

    private String fleetFirstName;
    private String serviceFirstName;

    ...

}
```

Service

```
public class MyService {

    // To avoid complexity maps the ThymeleafForm in different JPA entities 
    // Logic and repository calls
}
```

Repositories

```
public class FleetServiceRepositoryJPA {    
    //Database operations for fleet table
}

public class ServiceRepositoryJPA { 
    //Database operations for service table
}
```

Comment: I dont understand. What's that for?

Comment: You cannot work with fields of different objects in the same form. Thus, you need to put all the fields together in the same object and then split the form depending on your logic. The second option is to have two separated forms.

Comment: I cannot have two separated form. And I don't know how I can put the fields together in the same object.

Comment: why do I have to separate private String fleetFirstName and private String serviceFirstName. Where is the part that they become one. And what object will I put to th:field?

Comment: what if I only put firstName to the DTO? Then use the DTO object and save it to both service and fleet table? You think that will work?

Comment: I have a problem. When I am trying to save(Insert to the database) using the DTO object, I can't do it. It says I can only use the service and fleet object for the parameter of save(JPA).

Comment: I understand now.Big help. Thank you.